Weird Behavior of cmake's FetchContent_Declare on MacOS
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
include(FetchContent)
project(qluto4)


set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

message(STATUS "Fetching libiio from github")
FetchContent_Declare(
    libiio
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio
    GIT_TAG main
)

include_directories(build/_deps/libiio-build)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libiio)


When I want to build this project, it fails with the following error:
...
[ 30%] Built target iio
[ 31%] Building C object _deps/libiio-build/CMakeFiles/iio-compat.dir/compat.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object _deps/libiio-build/CMakeFiles/iio-compat.dir/dynamic-unix.c.o
[ 34%] Linking C shared library iio.framework/iio
Fixup Current symbolic link
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /Users/myzinsky/Programming/qluto4/build/iio.framework/Versions: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [_deps/libiio-build/iio.framework/Versions/0.99/iio] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file `_deps/libiio-build/iio.framework/Versions/0.99/iio'
make[1]: *** [_deps/libiio-build/CMakeFiles/iio-compat.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

So it seems that cmake places the generated framework iio.framework not where it actually expects it. I can find the file at:
build/_deps/libiio-build/iio.framewok

The libiio project uses CMAKE_BINARY_DIR variable when create the version file: CMakeLists.txt:374. Most likely, the project expects given directory to refer to the project's binary directory. But when uses as a subproject, given variable refers to the outer project's binary directory. Not every CMake project could be correctly built as a subproject, via add_subdirectory or FetchContent. Some projects could be built only standalone.

That's the final solution that I found.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(pluto17)
include(FetchContent)
include(ExternalProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

ExternalProject_Add(
    libiio
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio
    GIT_TAG v0.26
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
)

ExternalProject_Add(
    libad9361-iio
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libad9361-iio
    GIT_TAG v0.3
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DLIBIIO_INCLUDEDIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libiio-prefix/src/libiio/
        -DLIBIIO_LIBRARIES=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libiio-prefix/src/libiio-build/iio.framework/
)

add_executable(pluto17
    src/main.cpp
)

add_dependencies(pluto17 libiio libad9361-iio)

target_include_directories(pluto17
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libiio-prefix/src/libiio/
)

target_link_libraries(pluto17 PRIVATE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

